# Exibir espaço em branco para valor Null em Views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net

Quando mando algum valor `null` para minha *view*, e o Razor tenta renderizar o valor, é retornado uma *exception*. Existe uma maneira de, quando a *view* receber um valor *null*, renderizar este como um espaço em branco sem ter que ficar fazendo verificações com `if`?

Comment: Mostre um exemplo de código da sua view.

Answer (score 4):

Sim.

Suponha por exemplo que `@model` tem uma propriedade chamada `Numero` que veio nula por algum motivo. A boa prática para exibir o valor é assim:

```
@(Model.Numero ?? 0)
```

Este operador tem um nome pitoresco: [Operador de coalescência nula](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx). Lê-se assim:

> Usar `Model.Numero` se não for nulo. Caso contrário, use 0.

Como é um operador, você pode usar pra qualquer tipo de variável, não apenas inteiros.

Outra opção [é o operador ternário condicional](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx), que basicamente é um *if-then-else* de uma linha só. Este você pode usar quando precisar especificar o teste a ser feito:

```
@(Model.Numero > 0 ? Model.Numero : 0)
```

Ou seja:

> Se `Model.Numero` for maior que zero, use-o como valor. Caso contrário, use 0.

---

Pro caso do espaço em branco, algo assim pode atender bem:

```
@(Model.PropertyQuePodeVirNula ?? "")
```

Ou ainda:

```
@(Model.PropertyQuePodeVirNula != null ?? Model.PropertyQuePodeVirNula.ToString() : "")
```

Comment: Opa, não especifiquei muito bem a pergunta. Gostaria de fazer isso sem ter que fazer verificações com if, por exemplo.

Comment: Sem verificar não tem como.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o operador de propagação de nulos, disponível a partir do **C# 6.0**.

Segue o exemplo:

```
@Model?.Quantidade
```

Leia mais sobre o esse operador na documentação: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators.

Comment: interessante atualizar a resposta.